# wordpress get_users returns no result

Tags: wordpress

get_users returns an empty array.  I've checked my data and the key matches a user meta field in the DB.

```
function upd_check_key() {

    $key = get_query_var( 'upd' );

    if( !empty( $key ) ) :

        $user = get_users( array( 'meta_key' => 'upd_key', 'meta_value' => $key ) );

        if( is_array( $user ) ):

            //Get rank and add 5 points
            $rank = get_usermeta( $user->ID, 'upd_rank' );
            $new_rank = $rank+5;
            $update_rank = update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'upd_rank', $rank );


            //Get hit and increase by one.
            $hit = get_usermeta( $user->ID, 'upd_hit' );
            $new_hit = $hit+1;
            $update_hits = update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'upd_hit', $new_hit );

            echo '<h1>***************************************************************</h1>';
            echo '<h1>USERID: '.$user->ID.'</h1>';

        endif;

    endif;


    echo '<h1>USERRANK: '.$new_rank.'</h1>';
    echo '<h1>USERHITS: '.$new_hit.'</h1>';
    echo '<h1>UERKEY: '.$key.'</h1>';
    echo var_dump( $user );

}
```

The `var_dump` doesn't return anything, so I assume the array is empty.

Comment: are you sure it is entering in first `if` statement?

Comment: I actually got this handled last night.  I've had similar issues with the new wordpress `get_` functions before when trying to search by meta key and value.  I'm not sure, but I think you have to define some other info, like 'role'.  Solution was to user `WP_User_Query` rather than `get_users`.

Answer (score 0):

#### 2020: when `get_` and even `wp_get_` are definitely working.

For those visiting in posterity, please don't be afraid to try again with `get_users()`. It's a pretty reliable one-line wrapper for the `WP_User_Query`, which obviates the need to call `$query->get_results()`. Here's some verified, working code, that always filters my user by `first_name`:

```
$users = get_users(array(
    'number' => -1,
    'fields' => 'all',
    'meta_key' => 'first_name',
    'meta_value' => 'Benjamin'
)));
var_dump($users);
```